# it has show error when i am poting data 'str' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python, dictionary

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def compnay_list(request):
    """
    List all Compnays, or create a new Compnay.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        compnay = Company.objects.all()
        serializer = CompanySerializer(compnay, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            print(request.data.get('email'))
            user_id = User.objects.get(email=request.data.get('email')).id
            print(request.data)
            user_response = request.data.get('user_response')
            for item in user_response:
                item.update({"user": user_id})

            serializer = CompanySerializer(data=user_response)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        except User.DoesNotExist:

            print("Error:email not available")
```

Comment: Could you share the value of `user_response` or it's structure?

Comment: {"email":"gpa@narola.email",
"user_response" :{
        "name": "TCS",
        "vat_number": "2507",
        "logo": "xyz",
        "description": "this is tcs infotech",
        "is_head_quarter": true,
        "business_type": "IT"
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update `item` which is a string (`update` is a dict method).

Change:

```
user_response = request.data.get('user_response')
for item in user_response:
    item.update({"user": user_id})
```

To:

```
user_response = request.data.get('user_response')
user_response.update({"user": user_id})
```